# Split on numeric to letters excluding comma

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have a string containing "0,35mA" I now have the code below, which splits "0,35mA" into

"0"

","

"35"

"mA"

```
List<string> splittedString = new List<string>();
foreach (string strItem in strList)
{
    splittedString.AddRange(Regex.Matches(strItem, @"\D+|\d+")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value)
        .ToList());
}
```

What I want is the code to be splitted into

"0,35"

"mA"

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I believe you have just some little more to learn about regex to be able to achieve this simple task. For a simple input like this a simple group for the Interger Part and the decimal part will be able to catch the value and a group for the Unit is simple at this point : `(?<IntergerPart>\d+)(\.|,)(?<DecimalPart>\d+)(?<Unit>\w+)` or `(\d+)(\.|,)(\d+)(\w+)` With out the named group.

Comment: But it's unclear those kind of string can be tricky may I ask for a larger panel of input? Do you always have a decimal part and decimal separator? Do you handle ^ and exposant? Do you have space sometime? Do you validate that every Word after a Number is a unit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to tokenize the string into numbers and everything else.

A better regex approach is to *split* with a number matching pattern while wrapping the whole pattern into a capturing group so as to also get the matching parts into the resulting array.

Since you have `,` as a decimal separator, you may use

```
var results = Regex.Split(s, @"([-+]?[0-9]*,?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)")
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
        .ToList();
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5B-%2B%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D*%2C%3F%5B0-9%5D%2B%28%3F%3A%5BeE%5D%5B-%2B%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%2B%29%3F%29&i=0%2C35mA):

[image]

The regex is based on the pattern described in [Matching Floating Point Numbers with a Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html).

The `.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))` is necessary to get rid of empty items (if any).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that all your strings will have the same format.

So, try using this regex:

```
 string regex = "([\\d|,]{4})|[\\w]{2}";
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var st = "0,35mA";  

 var li = Regex.Matches(st, @"([,\d]+)([a-zA-z]+)").Cast<Match>().ToList();  

 foreach (var t in li)
 {
     Console.WriteLine($"Group 1 {t.Groups[1]}")
     Console.WriteLine($"Group 2 {t.Groups[2]}");
 }
```

Group 1 0,35

Group 2 mA